# Variance of difference of r.v.

Tags: probability

Let $\{\epsilon_i\}$ be independent variables, with $Var(\epsilon_i)=\sigma^2g_i$, where $g_i$ are constants.

What is the expression for $Var(\epsilon_i-\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n\epsilon_j}{n})$?

to obtain it, $\displaystyle Var(\epsilon_i-\frac{\sum\epsilon_j}{n})=Var((1-1/n)\epsilon_i-\frac{\sum_{j\neq i}\epsilon_j}{n})=(1-1/n)^2\sigma^2g_i+\frac{\sum_{j\neq i}\sigma^2g_j}{n^2}=(1-2/n)\sigma^2g_i+\frac{\sigma^2\sum g_j}{n^2}$.

When  $\forall_j$ $g_j=1$, this is supposed to give $\sigma^2$, but I get $1+1/n$ instead. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you should get $((1-2/n)+1/n)\sigma=(1-1/n)\sigma$, and this is correct. Why you think it should be $\sigma$? It is a little smaller.

Comment: you're right. I redid the exercise, and something from another part was missing. This is correct. Thanks. ;)